# Why are the normal modes in a CQED system centered around the dipole frequency instead of offset like in a classical coupled oscillator system?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, coupled-oscillators, cavity-qed

I am trying to understand the modified spontaneous emission spectrum from a dipole coupled to a cavity mode in terms of a classical coupled oscillator system.

The usual analogy made in a lot of CQED (Cavity Quantum ElectroDynamics) texts is that the coupled system is equivalent to two coupled oscillators with the same eigenfrequency $\omega_0$, respective damping rates $\gamma$ and $\kappa$ and a coupling rate $g$. The coupled system is then usually driven at a frequency $\omega$.

The resulting spectrum then usually has two peaks centered around $\omega_0$:

- $\omega_s = \omega_0 - g$
- $\omega_f = \omega_0 + g$

However in a classical oscillator, the spectrum normally has these two peaks:

- $\omega_s = \omega_0$
- $\omega_f = \sqrt{\omega_0^2+2g^2} \simeq \omega_0 + g^2/\omega_0$

I might have made some mistakes in the exact formulas here (depends on exact meaning of the rates, number of photons, etc), but the idea is that in the CQED case, the normal modes are centered on $\omega_0$, while in the classical case, they are not.

Why is that? And is it even possible to use the classical analogy to predict the modified emission spectrum or can this only be done by going through the proper quantum treatment?

And why does the classical solving usually involve coupled second order equations, while the CQED solving usually involves coupled first order differential equations?

Comment: There are two regimes of CQED, the perturbative and the strong coupling regime. I think the answer for the two will differ for the two. Which one would you like an answer for?

Comment: The strong coupling one. I almost forgot about this and then didn't have time to look more into it. I'm still interested in an answer though.

Comment: I will try to write something up, will take some time though. Also +1 now!